# Rails Commands Hanging with Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I'm trying to create a new Rails 6 app on Windows 10 machine.  However, when I try to run anything `rails` or `rake` commands, it hangs/freezes.  I discovered that it was tied to `Webpacker` when I was creating my DB.

```
C:\Sites\myapp> bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
```

When I terminated the job, it showed this:

```
rails aborted!
Interrupt:
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb:33:in ``'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb:33:in `block in <class:Engine>'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:362:in `initialize!'
C:/Sites/highbar/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `block in require'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load_dependency'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `require'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:338:in `require_environment!'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:514:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `block in execute'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `each'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `execute'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:238:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `each'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:238:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `each'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `invoke'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config => environment
```

When I comment out Webpacker in the gemfile, this worked, as did `rails s`.  As soon as I uncomment Webpacker, the commands freeze/hang again.

Is there anything that I need to do beyond `bundle exec rails webpacker:install`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My version of NodeJS was out of date.  When I updated NodeJS, I also needed to update Yarn.  After doing that, I'm able to run Rails 6 with Webpacker.